# Git remote push crashed

Tags: git, push, bitbucket, smartgit

I used Smartgit to push a repository to bit bucket. The push went through and I can see it on BitBucket but the Smartgit thread crashed.

So now my repository says that it is not in sync with BitBucket even though the push did go through.

What should now I do to get my local repository to say that it matches the remote origin?

Comment: I would recommend to use the command line and try to investigate whats wrong with your repository and fix it from there.

Comment: Any specific commands that I need to try? As I mentioned, nothing is wrong with the repository except that the push crashed halfway through. The pushed files did end up on BitBucket but my local repository did not register this.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use SmatGit to:

- delete the first clone
- clone again the BitBucket repo in a new location
- start from that new clone (which should then be "in sync")

Comment: You mean delete the BitBucket repository, and then create a new one and push again to this new repository?

Will the new BitBucket repository have the same push history as the existing one?

Comment: @JatinderThind If the push has succeeded, I don't see why you would need to delete the BitBucket repo: simply clone it again, and the new local clone would be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this fixed by pushing again from Smartgit. This marked my local repo as in sync with remote origin (BitBucket).